# Users in Guest role see default theme instead custom one for given layouts

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

Users in Guest role see default theme instead custom one for pages which inherit from defined custom theme. This seems to be very strange problem.

Even though layouts have specified to inherit theme from parent theme:

> Use the same look and feel of the Public Pages.

Guests see them as the one with regular Liferay theme. Any idea what can be causing such issue? Or anyone experienced similar problem?

I am almost sure this problem is related to layout revision functionality which we are using on our portal (or however is it called). From other hand, useful will be information about how Liferay is using these tables:

- layout
- layoutbranch
- layoutfriendlyurl
- layoutprototype
- layoutrevision
- layoutset
- layoutsetbranch
- layoutsetprototype

And how theme is inherited for layouts which defined option  "*Use the same look and feel of the Public Pages*"? Where this information is stored for each layout, which tells him to use parent theme instead his own defined one? Where parent theme information is stored (the one defined in Public Pages first layout tree element)?

Thanks for any information, which helps me to understand this mechanism and maybe solve my problem.

Comment: To clarify this: If you browse portalurl/web/guest/home as Guest user (not signed in) you see the portal render with the classic theme. If you browse the same URL as logged in User, you see the portal render with your theme. Did I understand the Problem? And one more question. Which Version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: @Gevatterjan We are using Liferay 6.2 EE with SP11. This is exactly as you said, except, this occurs only for sites where theme is defined as "Use the same look and feel of the Public Pages." option checked instead of choosing one theme.

Comment: And the public page of your site has the correct theme defined? Can you verify that?

Comment: Yup, correct one is defined.

Comment: I do have to admit, that I don't know what you mean by LayoutRevision. Do you have to approve something there so that everybody sees it.

Comment: Basically I mean mechanism responsible for 'Mark as Ready for Publication' which occurs for pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours consumed on analyzing our portal environment finally I managed to solve it. Here is the reason of such strange problem:

It turns out, the information about main parent theme (the one which can be inherited on child pages) is stored in different places for such options enabled on portal:

- different for option : **Page Versioning** - > **Enabled On Public Pages**
- different for option : **Page Versioning** - > **Disabled On Public Pages**

And after disabling such option it turns out main theme was set to default one, while with option enabled it was set to correct one.

Solution we used was to disable option of page versioning, change main parent theme for public sites, and then enable option of page versioning back again.

By the way, if you are awere of losing some important data configured on your versioned layouts, be sure to make backup before you start. I ended up with blank pages and had to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this actually a difference between public and private pages?

Guests can only see public pages.  Users can be on the private pages, and both of these can be set up completely differently.

Check the url in both cases and make sure they are actually the same.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but this is related to exactly same page in both scenarios. Case seems to be more complicated and I guess it is related to some specified Liferay issue. I am just hoping now, I will be able to find out what is the problem and solve it myself. Or there is any slightest chance someone managed to stuck in the same place as me ;-)